# 2 tiered horizontal navigation bar

Tags: css, navigation

Wondered if anyone had any links to a tutorial for a navigation bar in css (not javascript). I'm after a 2 tier horizontal bar. the bottom tier being also horizontal.

Just like the following image

[image]

any pointers would be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[cssplay.co.uk](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/) has plenty of dropline menus. Just look under "Multi-Level - Dropline". Pay attention to copyright though.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, didnt know they were called dropline. Another question which could just be me being stupid but where's the download button on that site!

Comment: There is no download button, inconvenient, I know. Code is always between <div id="info">.....</div> tags, and style is usually between head tags and not in external .css file.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just mean two tiers, and they are both visible all the time, not that the second tier is visible on hover, correct?

If so, here's a basic fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/XAE9c/

Anyway, the idea is to use two `ul` lists, and place the `li` elements of your nav in them accordingly. You can then style the list items however you want from there, as well as add links to their content, etc.

If you have a dynamic page, you would do a simple server-side check for `if ($PageURL == "blah.php") {` and spit out `class="active"` on the current tab, and style that however you like.

I'd suggest using inspect element on some nav bars you like, and going from there.

Comment: That's what I thought, it's just that everyone else was posting Javascript solutions, and so I wasn't sure. Incidentally, if you DID want to show the secondary nav on hover without using JS, you could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/jblasco/XAE9c/2/

Answer (score 0):

The solution without Javascript for IE hover hack http://webstuffshare.com/demo/New-CSSTabMenu
but it may not behave in the way you want, are you after reveal on hover?
http://www.webstuffshare.com/2010/01/updated-pure-css-tab-menu/

Answer (score -1):

THE guide: Suckerfish Dropdowns.

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/dropdowns

You'd just modify the styles to be fully horizontal.

Comment: that makes use of javascript. I'm not that fussed with IE6. Does IE7+ make use of the hover function things other than links?

Comment: I believe so, though if you read the article, you'll understand why you need JS for that part.

Comment: Awful (hotlinked) resource. Code tutorial is verbose and the link to the working example is obfuscated with comments. Yuck.

Comment: @7SpecialGems you're trashing A List Apart? And you're mad enough about it to downvote a 3-year old answer? (By current guidelines, this whole question should be closed.)

Comment: @7SpecialGems what does "obfuscated by comments" even mean?